# Twig extension: render template with variables

Tags: twig, symfony

I have created a twig extension te render a view with some variables , but I have this error

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") 
in :Backend\twig:activate.html.twig at line 1.
```

This is the Class extension:

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class ActivateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('activate', array($this, 'booleanFilter'), array('is_safe' => array('html'),
                'needs_environment' => true)),
        );
    }

    public function booleanFilter(\Twig_Environment $twig, $var1, $var2)
    {

        return $twig->render(':Backend/twig:activate.html.twig', array(
            'var1' => $var1,
            'var2' => $var2
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'activate_extension';
    }
}
```

this is the view to be rendred:

```
//test
{{ var1 }}<br>
{{ var2 }}
```

and this is how the filter is called in the other view:

```
{{ entity.activate|activate('test var1', 'test var2') }}
```

Comment: probably is better you define a twig_function instead of a filter: the filter take as argument the elem you want to filter so the input of the function is `entity.activate` istead of  `'test var1', 'test var2'`

Comment: ah , ok I'll try it thanks

Comment: Hi @hous is not necessary to develop a function instead of a filters, read my answer about what I find in the doc. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the TWIG developer guide about [Filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters):

> When called by Twig, the PHP callable receives the left side of the
>   filter (before the pipe |) as the first argument and the extra
>   arguments passed to the filter (within parentheses ()) as extra
>   arguments.

So the first argument of the php function is the value of `entity.activate` probably the array of the errors, then the other params are passed as arguments. As example you should change your filters as follow:

```
public function booleanFilter(\Twig_Environment $twig, $activate, $var1, $var2)
{

    return $twig->render(':Backend/twig:activate.html.twig', array(
        'var1' => $var1,
        'var2' => $var2
    ));
}
```

Hope this help. Sorry for my comment about twig functions

Comment: Thank you very much